# Easiest way to automating updating msi files for deployment?

Tags: windows-installer, deployment, msdn

Recently, I was assigned to find a method to automate our updating of .msi files (firefox, adobe reader, etc..) that we use for deployment. What is the best method automating this process? Is there a gui software out there that we may use or should I write a script? Is there a one stop database/site which has the most recently made .msi files? If I were required to write a script to update these files, which would be the best language to code in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get software like Advanced Installer or Wise Installer that let you install the package on a baseline system, configure it how you want it, and then create a custom install from that.  If you really want to be slick you use something like Puppet or SUS to push it out to the boxes it applies to.

Comment: Appreciate the advice and suggestions!

Comment: It's *the* easiest and most fool-proof way I know to build something like that. The automated stuff doesn't miss a registry key or a file in a weird location or whatever.  The right package is smart enough to put things $USER home directory (vs. "BobInIT"'s home directory) with one of the tools.  Just google custom install creator or something similar and you'll get plenty of options.  One should be in your boss' price range.